# PHP - Payments online directly with credit cards

Tags: php, payment-gateway, credit-card, payment-processing

I know how to integrate payments with paypal, but I need to be able to let the customers pay directly with their credit cards.

Is there anyone willing to explain very briefly and simple what exactly I need to do ?

So far the only services I found are google wallet and http://www.authorize.net/ but I don't understand very well the steps I have to do to integrate them and which one of them are better.

The website is located in Italy if this matters, and the server-side language is PHP.

If you can't explain at least please give me some tutorials/books where to start and I'll try to do it.

Comment: please look this. there are many project are here
https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=authorize+net&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories

Comment: I know API's but I need some guidance to integrate them and best practice how to use, I never used API's before.

Comment: Such questions are [not appropriate for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq) and will be [closed](http://bit.ly/18T95z1) or [deleted](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR). Be sure to familiarize yourself with [what type of questions you can or should ask](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc). If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J) or check the [FAQ] and see [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page for general information.